# Percona on EC2 timeout errors

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, timeout, percona

I am setting up a new Percona node on an AWS to connect to an existing cluster that is not on AWS. I have security groups updated.
I added all the IPs to the my.cnf file and could not start Percona. I removed the IPs to start from scratch. I am getting this error:

```
140114 16:24:30 [ERROR] WSREP: failed to open gcomm backend connection: 110: failed to reach primary view: 110 (Connection timed out)
         at gcomm/src/pc.cpp:connect():139
140114 16:24:30 [ERROR] WSREP: gcs/src/gcs_core.c:gcs_core_open():195: Failed to open backend connection: -110 (Connection timed out)
140114 16:24:30 [ERROR] WSREP: gcs/src/gcs.c:gcs_open():1289: Failed to open channel 'my_centos_cluster' at 'gcomm://10.10.25.10,10.20.4.11,10.10.20.12,10.20.4.13': -110 (Connection timed out)
140114 16:24:30 [ERROR] WSREP: gcs connect failed: Connection timed out
140114 16:24:30 [ERROR] WSREP: wsrep::connect() failed: 6
140114 16:24:30 [ERROR] Aborting
```

That is only a sample. Here is my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]

#datadir=/var/lib/mysql 
datadir=/data/mysql
user=mysql
log-error=/data/mysql/mysqlerror.log

# Path to Galera library 
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib64/libgalera_smm.so

# Cluster connection URL contains the IPs of node#1, node#2 and node#3 
wsrep_cluster_address=gcomm://LOCAL_IP

# In order for Galera to work correctly binlog format should be ROW 
binlog_format=ROW

# MyISAM storage engine has only experimental support 
default_storage_engine=InnoDB

# This is a recommended tuning variable for performance 
innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog=1

# This changes how InnoDB autoincrement locks are managed and is a requirement for Galera 
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2

# Node #1 address 
wsrep_node_address=LOCAL_IP

# SST method 
wsrep_sst_method=xtrabackup

# Cluster name 
wsrep_cluster_name=my_centos_cluster

# Authentication for SST method 
wsrep_sst_auth="USER:PASS"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How does this node connect to the others, if they're not on AWS? It looks like they're on a private network...

Comment: I get that. But shouldn't the AWS node be able to start up if leave it as a standlone node?